# Alternative to Lenovo "Conservation Mode"

Tags: battery, battery-life, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Y50-70, which I am doing a clean install of Win8.1 on (A new SSD) The Battery software that comes with it out of the box contains a very useful battery conservation mode.

This stops the battery being charged beyond 60%, which obviously helps with the health of the battery, makes it last longer etc. I use this feature a lot as the Laptop only goes to two places, and is immediately plugged in to power.

As the clean install obviously won't include Lenovo's battery software, is there any native or third-party alternatives that have a similar function?

I obviously could just install the Lenovo software again, but I don't want all the crapware that comes with it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the Lenovo Energy Management software that you are talking about on my G50-45. I came to know a little bit about the software when I was setting up my laptop for the first time. Here is what I learned.

After I have installed Windows and all its drivers I noticed there was still one unknown device under Device Manager. Now I didn't installed any of Lenovo's software or bloatware till that point only the drivers. So at first I let Windows to search the internet to identify and install the unknown device's driver. It was unsuccessful. All my devices were up and running fine so I couldn't figure out which device driver I missed. Then I realized that the unknown device's driver must be in one of those Lenovo's bloatware. I suspected the Energy Management software the most so I installed it and there it was the unknown device vanished from the Device Manager.

So here is what I concluded. I figured that Lenovo might be using some sort of proprietary battery management device in their laptops these days. So for such proprietary devices to function properly there is really no substitute for the original driver or software. So its best you use Lenovo's Energy Management software because other third party software may not function properly and might turn out useless. And to be honest Lenovo's Energy Management isn't that bad it does its job well and there is no garbage installed with it. I am not a huge fan of any of those software or bloatware that comes along with any laptop but I like that little piece of software simply because its effective.

Comment: Interesting! I'll take a look at what comes with it.

Comment: @harley_woop only install the Energy Management software and nothing else from Lenovo. There is no garbage packed with it, I have been using it for 2-3 months now. You want me to provide you the link?

Comment: I found it - http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds100275